# Prove that $D[x]$ is an integral domain if $D$ is one.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Prove if $D$ is an integral domain and $f,g\in D[X]$ are nonzero, then $fg$ does not equal $0$ and $\deg[f(x)g(x)]=\deg f(x) + \deg g(x)$.

I do not know much about this since I just learned about it. Here is what I can prove for you. Please tell me if I am right. If not, please provide a proof.

Proof: Write $f(x) = a_0 + \dots + a_nx^{n}$ and $g(x) = b_0 + \dots + b_mx^m$, with $a_m$, $b_m$ nonzero. Then $f(x)g(x) = a_0b_0 + (a_0b_1 + a_1b_0)x + \dots + a_nb_mx^{n+m}$.

The largest power of $x$ that can occur is $x^{n+m}$ so $\deg [f(x)g(x)] \leq \deg f(x) + \deg g(x)$. If $D$ has no zero divisors, then $a_nb_m$ does not equal zero and $n+m$ is the degree giving us $\deg[f(x)g(x)]=\deg f(x) + \deg g(x)$.

Comment: That's fine. This certainly isn't (measure-theory), isn't (group-theory) either, and is better tagged as (abstract-algebra) than (number-theory), the latter being reserved for deeper stuff.

Comment: your proof is fine.

Comment: Thanks. Is there an easier way to prove this though?

Comment: it's pretty easy the way you have it: the degree of $f(x)g(x)$ is at most $m+n$, and in this case it actually is because $D$ is an integral domain, making $a_nb_m\neq 0$.

Comment: I would suspect there is no easier way to prove the degree equation. Perhaps there is a nice way to show that $D[x]$ is an integral domain using some more advanced ring theory though.

Comment: @rotten Thanks for telling me that.

Comment: @user1. Thanks but I did not learn ring theory yet. Is it possible you can show me what it looks like.

Answer (score 4):

(Just to leave an answer:) Your proof is correct and is the standard one.  It's so short and straightforward that it's hard to see room for improvement.